# Should I be returning DB results inside the function or loop through the results outside the function?

Tags: php, function

So I was wondering what's the best way/practise of querying the database in a function and then printing the results back to the `.php` page. I got taught to do the query in the `function()`, call the `function()` inside the `.php` page and then loop through the resultset inside the `.php` page.

Here is an example of what i'm doing now - Im wondering if this is "Unsafe" or "Not secure" or slower than returning the results in the function? Because at the moment - This is taking a while to load on the page? Could this be because I'm doing using if statements inside the `while loop`?

```
     showPlaylist($staticTestUser);


    if($numRecords == 0){
            echo "<div class='no-found'>No playlists found</div>";
        }
        else{
                $htmloutput = "<div class='playlist-wrap'>";

            $i = 1;
            while($arrRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $title = $arrRows['song-title']
                    $thumbnail=$arrRows['thumb']

                    $playTitle = $arrRows['playlistName'];
                    $htmloutput .= "<div class='playlist-head'>";
                    //Make sure the title is only shown once - Loop through the rest.
                    if($i == 1){
                        $htmloutput .= $playTitle;
                    }

                    $htmloutput .= "</div>";
                    $htmloutput .= "<div class='playlist-item'>";
                        $htmloutput .= "<div class='play-thumb'>".$thumbnail."</div>";
                        $htmloutput .= "<div class='play-title'>".substr($title, 0,30)."...</div>";
                    $htmloutput .= "</div>";

                    if($i == $numRecords){
                    $playId = $arrRows['pID'];
                    $htmloutput .= "<div class='playlist-footer'>";
                        $htmloutput .= "<div class='play-stats'>";
                        $htmloutput .= "Likes:".$arrRows['likes']." -- Dislikes: ".$arrRows['dislikes'];
                        $htmloutput .= "</div>";
                        $htmloutput .= "<div class='play-vote'>";
                        $htmloutput .= "<button name='playLike' type='submit' value='$playId'>Like</button>";
                        $htmloutput .= "<button name='playDislike' type='submit' value='$playId'>Dislike</button>"; 
                        $htmloutput .= "</div>";
                    $htmloutput .= "</div>";
                }
                $i++;
                    unset($playTitle);
            }
            $htmloutput .= "</div>";

                echo $htmloutput;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any specific security issues with your code that I can see, but best practice right now is to use the MVC - model, view, controller - design pattern. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Or the MVP - model, view, presenter - design pattern. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter). Both are very similar.

Using one of these patterns has many benefits but the biggest ones in my opinion are code readable, portability, and reusability. It may also speed things up as well.

The if statements inside your code wouldn't be whats slowing your code down - it would probably be the repeated fetch at the beginning of the while loop.

Comment: Those frameworks are for object oriented programming? Are they not? I mean I could convert my some parts into classes and just reuse them again and again. - E.g http://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

Comment: Sort of. They work really well with OOP but don't depend on it. The main idea of them is to separate the view, logic, and database from each other. You could do your own scaled down version of MVC without using an entire framework (though if your application is large a framework is definately worth it). Just put your output in a view, then pass in the result object your query returned. Then inside the view do some sort of for each loop through all the rows in the result set and display with whatever other formatting you want.

Comment: thanks! would you know how I can limit the results of an SQL query so I only get 1 **playlist-name** result per **playlist id**?

Comment: Add "LIMIT 1" to the query - see here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp for more info